# clearTimeout Function not working properly on dialog when open

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i attached  my code. am clear the time out function when dialog is open.but its not working properly.When i open my dialog the count down decreasing from 20 but in between 20 seconds if i close and open the dialog , the timing is collapsing each other.

```
function(){
    var time =20;
    flag = false;       
    clearTimeout(startTimer);       
    startTimer = function(){            
        if(!flag){              
            var finTime = time - 1;
            time = finTime;             
            setTimeout(startTimer,1000);                
            if(time==0){                    
                flag = true;        }               
            $("#input").text(time);             
         } else {                
             clearTimeout(startTimer,1000);                          
         } 
    };

    setTimeout(startTimer,1000);

};
```

I have tried this code also

```
dialogOpen = function(){

    $("#dialog").dialog('open');

    startTimer();
    stopTimer();
}

startTimer = function() {

    time = 20;      
    flag = false;       
    setTimeout(startTime, 1000);
};

stopTimer = function() {

    flag = true;        
    time = 0;       
    clearTimeout(startTime);
};

startTime = function(){

    if(!flag){

        var finTime = time - 1;

        time = finTime;         

        setTimeout(startTime,1000);

        if(time==0){                
            flag = true;
        }
        $("#input").text(time);         
     } else {            
         clearTimeout(Time);                         
     } 
};
```

Comment: When i open my dialog again and again its not clear the previous  time out

Comment: `clearTimeout()` doesn't take a function as a parameter, it takes a timeout ID as returned by `setTimeout()`. Did you look at any [`clearTimeout()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign `setTimeout` to a variable

```
var timer;    
timer = setTimeout(startTimer,1000);
```

and you can clear the `setTimeout` using `clearTimeout` by passing the variable.

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

Comment: ya i tried that also. I set that variable as global.Is the any mistake to set var as global

Comment: I don't see you have set a variable global in your code you provided.

Comment: Sry, I mentioned in my prog.Didnt  mention here.But one global variable called startTimer is there.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Working well. I should set the timer as variable rather a function.

Answer (score 1):

To call `clearTimeout()` you want to pass in the `intervalVariable` that was returned by `setTimeout()`, not the function, so it would look like:

```
var intervalVariable = setTimeout(startTimer,1000);
clearTimeout(intervalVariable);
```

It's best to thing of `intervalVariable` as the ID for the timeout that is then used by the browser to cancel it.

Set a global variable before your `startTimer` function, then set it to the return of `setTimeout()` and use it in place of `startTimer` in `clearTimeout()`.